# Is there a way to cast an SystemVerilog assignment pattern into a packed struct?

Tags: system-verilog

Per the System Verilog LRM "Assignment pattern format", a data structure can be printed into a string as follows:

```
module top;
 typedef enum {ON, OFF} switch_e;
 typedef struct {switch_e sw; string s;} pair_t;
 pair_t va[int] = '{10:'{OFF, "switch10"}, 20:'{ON, "switch20"}};
 initial begin
  $display("va[int] = %p;",va);
  $display("va[int] = %0p;",va);
  $display("va[10].s = %p;", va[10].s);
 end
endmodule : top

This example may print:
va[int] = '{10:'{sw:OFF, s:"switch10"}, 20:'{sw:ON, s:"switch20"}} ;
va[int] = '{10:'{OFF, "switch10"}, 20:'{ON, "switch20"}} ;
va[10].s = "switch10";
```

Is there a way to do the reverse?  What I'd like to do is to take an assignment pattern string as a plusarg or a line read from a file, and assign that to a variable at run time, e.g.:

```
string assign_pattern = "'{10:'{sw:OFF, s:"switch10"}, 20:'{sw:ON, s:"switch20"}}";
$cast(va, assign_pattern); // ** This doesn't work **
```

If not generally possible, is there a way to do that specifically for packed struct types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do the reverse. SystemVerilog was designed as a compiled language—there's no parser available at run-time. You would have to create a parser in SystemVerilog or C smart enough to decode the assignment patterns you expect to read in.

Another option is converting the file of assignment patterns into code that could be compiled in with the rest of your code.

### Another option based on your comments

You can use a bit-stream or streaming operator to *parse* a bit-string into a `struct`. The struct does not need to be packed, it just needs to be made up from fixed-sized, integral values.

```
module top;
  typedef enum bit [1:0] {ON, OFF, INBETWEEN} switch_e;
  typedef struct {switch_e sw; bit [8*8:1] s; bit [5:0] value;} trio_s; // 72 bits
  typedef bit [71:0] uint72_t;

  trio_s v,x;
  uint72_t l;
  initial begin
    x = '{sw:OFF, s:"switch10", value:'h0a};
    l = uint72_t'(x);
    $displayh(l);
    v = trio_s'(l);
    $displayh("v = %p",v);
    $display("v.s = %s",v.s);
  end
endmodule
```

This displays

```
# 5cddda5d18da0c4c0a
# v = '{sw:OFF, s:8320234785195176240, value:10}
# v.s = switch10
```

Comment: It seems like %p was added as a compile-time solution as it's trivial to generate assignment statements that may be included in a subsequent compile.  However, for larger designs the costs of having to recompile is so large compared to doing this parsing at run time.  I was hoping there was some standard system call to do this that I may have overlooked.  Absent that, the next best option is if there is open source VPI code that can do this (not necessarily storing data as assignment patterns but any human-readable/easily editable format e.g. JSON/YAML/XML)

Comment: system verilog is **not** a *scripting* language. You cannot generate code which could be interpreted by it in the same compilation path.  You can use vpi, as you mentioned, or do similar things in just plane verilog, check file read/write functions: $fopen/read/write. You should probably look into the `$readmem` functions.

Answer (score 0):

`pair_t va[int] = '{10:'{OFF, "switch10"}, 20:'{ON, "switch20"}};`

is the same as

```
pair_t va[int] 
initial begin 
  va[10].sw = OFF;
  va[10].s = "switch10";
  ..
```

Saying that, you can write your own parser of a +arg string (or strings) which will assign values to the array fields in a task. This is the only possibility. For exmple:

```
 string indx = "1";
 string sw = "off";
 initial begin
   int i = indx.atoi();
   va[i].sw = sw == "off" ? OFF : ON; 
   ...
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid writing custom parsing logic in SystemVerilog.  If need be, I would store data as binary data, then have an external script convert from that into human-readable structures that can be edited, and have scripts to do the reverse conversion back into binary data.   That's easier to do for packed structs, which is my intended use case.

Comment: well, in this case there is no solution in system verilog for your problem as you described it in the question.